# Traer los datos de un modelo de usuario en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Por alguna razón, el comando que uso para que traiga los datos de un modelo, no esta funcionando bien en este caso. No muestra los datos para nada, me gustaría saber si hay una manera de traer esos datos correctamente

Los datos que intento traer son los del email y el tipo de usuario

Este es mi modelo. User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    const ADMIN_TYPE = 'admin';
    const DEFAULT_TYPE = 'cliente';

public function isAdmin(){        
    return $this->type === self::ADMIN_TYPE;    
}

    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [ //Determina los datos que se pueden meter
        'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [ //Esconde la clave
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Este es mi controlador, en el método getProfile es donde tengo el problema. No trae los datos que debe tener el modelo, los cuales están en la base de datos

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
use Redirect;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getSignup(){
        return view('user.signup'); //Manda al usuario al signup
    }

    public function postSignup(Request $request){ //Crear el usuario
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'email|required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:4',
            'type' => User::DEFAULT_TYPE,
        ]); //Valida al usuario deacuerdo si es unico y su clave es mayor a 4

        $user=new User([
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),

        ]);

        $user->save(); //Salva al usuario
        Auth::login($user); //Arranca la sesion
        return redirect()->route('user.profile');
    }

    public function getSignin(){
        return view('user.signin');
    }

    public function postSignin(Request $request){ //Inicio de sesion
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'email|required',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
        ]); //Valida los campos

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password'), 'type' => 'cliente'])){
          return redirect()->route('user.profile');
        } //Valida si el usuario es un cliente

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password'), 'type' => 'admin'])){
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
          } //Valida si el usuario es un admin

        return redirect()->back();
        }

    public function getProfile(){
        $users = DB::table('users')->where('id','=',$id)->get(); //Quiero agarrar la id del usuario actual, la cual esta definida arriba
        return view('user.profile', compact('users', $users));
    }

    public function getLogout(){
      Auth::logout();
      return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }
    }
```

Este es mi view, no muestra los datos que le pido que traiga el controlador de UserController mediante el método que esta arriba en getProfile, simplemente muestra los datos en blanco

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
   <h1>Perfil </h1>
   <h2>Email: {{ $users->email }}</h2>
   <h2>Tipo de usuario: {{ $users->type }}</h2>
   </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Esta es la ruta que usa

```
Route::get('/profile', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getProfile',
    'as' => 'user.profile' //Es el modulo de perfil, solo usuarios registrados lo pueden ver
]);
```

Edit: Mis rutas en web.php completas

```
<?php

   //Invoca al controlador ProductController para que muestre el index
    Route::get('/', [
        'uses' => 'ProductController@getIndex',
        'as' => 'product.index'
    ]);

    //Invoca al controlador ProductController para que meta cosas en el carrito
    Route::get('/shopping-cart/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'ProductController@getAddToCart',
        'as'=> 'product.addToCart',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);

    //Invoca al controlador ProductController para que meta cosas en el carrito
    Route::get('/shopping-cart/', [
        'uses' => 'ProductController@getCart',
        'as'=> 'product.shoppingCart',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);

    Route::get('/checkout', [
        'uses' => 'ProductController@getCheckout',
        'as'=> 'checkout',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);

    Route::post('/checkout', [
        'uses' => 'ProductController@postCheckout',
        'as'=> 'checkout',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);

     //Invoca al controlador de Usuarios y hace diversas funciones
     Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function() {

        Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function() {
          Route::get('/signup', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@getSignup',
            'as' => 'user.signup'  //Es el modulo de registro, solo usuarios no registrados lo pueden usar
        ]);

        Route::post('/signup', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@postSignup', 
            'as' => 'user.signup' //Es el modulo de registro, cuando el usuario se registra, solo usuarios no registrados lo pueden usar
        ]);

        Route::get('/signin', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@getSignin',
            'as' => 'user.signin' //Es el modulo de inicio de sesion, solo usuarios no registrados lo pueden usar
        ]);

        Route::post('/signin', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@postSignin', 
            'as' => 'user.signin' //Es el modulo de inicio de sesion, cuando el usuario inicia sesion, solo usuarios no registrados lo pueden usar
        ]);
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
        Route::get('/profile/{id}', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@getProfile',
            'as' => 'user.profile' //Es el modulo de perfil, solo usuarios registrados lo pueden ver
        ]);

        Route::get('/logout', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@getLogout',
            'as' => 'user.logout'  //Es el modulo de salir, solo usuarios registrados lo pueden usar
        ]);

    });
    });

    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@admin')    
        ->middleware('is_admin')    
        ->name('admin.dashboard');
```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que tienes los siguientes errores:

1. Si tu ruta `/profile` sirve para obtener el perfil de un solo usuario delimitado por su `id`, entonces debería lucir así:

Es decir le estamos pasando como parámetro necesario una variable llamada `id` la cual será dinámica al tomar el valor *numérico* usado para filtrar al usuario

Código

```
Route::get('/profile/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getProfile',
    'as' => 'user.profile' //Es el modulo de perfil, solo usuarios registrados lo pueden ver
]);
```

1. Segundo, en tu consulta te hace falta indicar que dicho método `getProfile()` reciba la variable `$id` así podrás usarla a nivel de tu consulta y filtrar por el valor que el usuario mnande vía *URI*

Código:

```
public function getProfile($id){
    $users = User::whereId($id)->first(); 
    return view('user.profile', compact('users', $users));
}
```

Ahora en tu vista para iterar los datos deberías hacer esto

```
    {{ $users->columna1 }}
    {{ $users->columna2 }}
```

Además de eso:

- Dado que tienes el modelo `User` fue el que usé para componer la consulta, no hace falta el query builder
- Use `whereId` tomando como referencia el nombre de la columna por la cual deseas filtrar
- Dado que solo buscas filtrar y obtener una instancia del modelo por medio de su `id`, entonces sustituye el uso de `get()` por el método `first()` en la consulta

**Referencias**

- [first method Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

Comment: Buenas. Ahora me sale el error "Missing required parameters for [Route: user.profile] [URI: user/profile/{id}"

Comment: Puse todas mis rutas completas, para ver si eso ayuda

Comment: Hice eso y me dio el error "Property [email] does not exist on this collection instance"

Comment: Logre resolver. Resulta que faltaba cambiar el menu para que dijera href="{{ route('user.profile', auth()->user()->id) }}"

Comment: Que bien @Shredder un gusto ayudarte y que encontraras lo faltante